# Pointer don't lets auto variable to get deleted after the function call

Tags: c, pointers, scope, dereference, automatic-storage

When I use a pointer instead of referencing operator in a function pointer do not allow auto variable to get deleted after function call.

I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` from this code because `int i=7;` is an auto variable and after the function call it gets deleted.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *func() {
  int i = 7;
  return &i;
}

int main(void) {
  int *a;
  a = func();
  printf("%d", *(a));

  return 1;
}
```

But when I use an extra pointer instead of referencing operator I do not get any error and get 7 as output. Why this pointer don't allow to delete variable i?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *func() {
  int i = 7;
  int *ip = &i;
  return ip;
}

int main(void) {
  int *a;
  a = func();
  printf("%d", *(a));

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: "do not allow auto variable to get deleted after function call." The variable is deleted. You are not allowed to look at that memory location.

Comment: "... auto variable to get deleted after function call." Well, on most systems variables with automatic storage duration isn't really deleted when a function returns. Your variable `i` is (on most systems) still present in stack memory with the value 7. So as long as that part of the stack hasn't been used by other code (typically a function call), you'll read the value 7 **if** you have the correct pointer value to that memory. In your first code example it is most likely the compiler that decides to return NULL instead of the real `&i`. It is allowed to do that ....

Comment: .... because it can see that it is a pointer to a local variable.  In the second example it seems the compiler "can't see" that `ip` is also pointing to a local variable so the actual value is returned and you can access the value of `i` using that pointer. That's what my `gcc` compiler do. Instead of `printf("%d",*(a));` try `printf("%p", (void*)a);` In both cases your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: So because of it this is something should not to do. It has an undefined behaviour and its result can changed between systems.

Comment: @Gerhardh, it's even worse. All copies of this pointer become indeterminate. Any use of their values results in UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The both programs have undefined behavior because after calling the function `func` there is an attempt to dereference an invalid pointer that does not point to an existent object.

Comment: The second one always prints 7 and returns 1.

Comment: @A_normal_guy Undefined behavior means that anything can occur even an expected result. But in any case such a program is incorrect.

Comment: @A_normal_guy 1) try to put another function call before `printf` and see if it changes. 2) Accessing that address is forbidden. You musn't even know that value.

Comment: @A_normal_guy google "c undefined behaviour"